# Google Detecting Japanese as English in voice recognition

Tags: voice-recognition

I have created a voice controlled android application. I am giving option to change the locale to Japanese with English being the default one.

The Japanese TTS works perfectly fine. But when the voice recognition  comes into picture, the Japanese words are recognized as English words and hence matched with the English words for possible match. Here, the mismatch occurs and hence my problem.

Is there any way google supports Japanese voice recognition.

Comment: You may try Nuance for the same

Comment: Nuance provides a limit over its API usage. I don't want that..

Comment: Google does support Japanese. How are you setting the language for the voice recognition?

Comment: I am using its intent and setting it like this:     intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,(Locale.JAPANESE);

Comment: Instead of `Locale.JAPANESE` try the String `ja-JP`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this if someone else finds this post helpful:

After months of RnD, I found another more accurate offline voice recognition engine i.e Julius. its hard to configure, yet the results are far better  than google.
Providing the link below:
https://github.com/tech-sketch/JuliusForAndroid